# Python type hinting: when to use MutableSequence vs List

Tags: python, list, sequence, type-hinting, python-typing

I have been reading about `typing.Sequence` and `typing.MutableSequence`.  There isn't a ton of "light reading" out there on either of the two, everything goes straight into details.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55166100/11163122) to [Can you specify variance in a Python type annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55154847/can-you-specify-variance-in-a-python-type-annotation)

> Sequence is the read-only version of List

So that leads me to wonder, what is the difference between `MutableSequence`, and just a plain `List`?

---

**More Details**

The best source I could find was the [The standard type hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) section of the Python Data model.

From reading the section `Mutable sequences`, it seems like `MutableSequence` might be a "parent" of `List`?

In other words, one can use them interchangeably, just `MutableSequence` is a bit less restrictive?

Comment: `Sequence` is not a read-only version of `List`. The answer you read was wrong about that.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica from reading `Lists` (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#lists), it says "Lists are mutable sequences".  So am I correct in my understanding that `MutableSequence` is a superset of `List`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer: Depending on how you interpret superset, you may be viewing this backwards; `List` is a superset of `MutableSequence`'s guaranteed features. `MutableSequence` is the minimum requirement, but a `list` can do stuff that not all `MutableSequence`s can do, e.g. `list` can hold any object, while other mutable sequences like `array.array` are limited to numeric types in specific ranges.

Comment: Yes @ShadowRanger good point.  I have changed my wording in the question from "superset" to "parent", for clarity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MutableSequence` represents arbitrary mutable sequences. For example, an instance of [`array.array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) satisfies `MutableSequence`.

`List` is specifically just lists. If an object is not a list, it doesn't satisfy `List`.

Use `MutableSequence` when you want to express "mutable sequence". Use `List` when you want to express "list".